# Not sure what/what not to put in classes in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm very new to Python and programming.  Say I have a text file that has a a bunch of people's names, articles they've written, and their assigned ID.  I made a class with these attributes and put that text file through the class.  No problem.  Now, the user is prompted to enter someone's name from that text file and all of the articles by that person is to be printed.  My question is this:  Do I do this by creating a new function inside of the class? Or do I create it outside of the class?

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around when and when not to touch a class.  I think I get that a class defines the attributes to an object.  However, when I add an object to the class, I'm finding difficulty referencing that object outside of the class.  Say, when asking the user to enter a name and comparing it to an object.

I get that this isn't the greatest question and I'm sure some will scold me for posting.  I'm just running out of options and I'm desperate for help.  I'm reading books, doing online tutorials, watching videos, and it's not clicking like it should.  I understand if this gets deleted.

AHA! Thank you all for the replies! I was able to set up the function outside of the class and compare the input variable to the author attribute in that class and KA-BLAMO!  It prints correctly!  I still have a lot to learn but it's moments like this that turn me into a giddy little school-girl.  Thank you all so much for your help and for being so nice!

Comment: You're right, OP, this isn't really on-topic as it's more about code design than coding itself. I'd be happy to help you in chat, but you don't have enough reputation =/

Comment: Dang.  Well, thanks anyways.  I'll keep on truckin'.

Comment: I believe your question would well fit on https://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2813623 I flagged the post to move to programmers.stackexchange.com as per Cilyan. As a quick thought: think of classes as discrete objects. You may have a `class Author` that has a list of works, or a `class Library` that has a list of `class Work` items that may have a lookup function (it would make sense to go into a `Library` and `.lookup(author_name)` wouldn't it?)

Answer (score 1):

Classes are a lynchpin of classical object-oriented programming, in that classes define the data and behavior of objects. In your case, you should ask yourself if it's appropriate for the class to print all the articles by the person. But you don't quite give enough information about your class for me to venture an opinion on that directly. A class to represent authors might look like:

```
class Author:
    def __init__(self, name, articles):
        self.name = name
        self.articles = articles
```

But this class doesn't know about more than one author, so it doesn't make sense for it to have a method to search through a list of authors. But does it make sense to define another class to represent a collection of authors? You know your requirements better than I do, but I wouldn't assume so. Python does collections pretty well internally.

Ultimately, my advice would be to create objects (by way of classes) that model the real-world things you're trying to represent in code. They should have data and behaviors (read: properties and methods) that make sense in the context of that model. You're fortunate that Python doesn't enforce the hobgoblin of rigid everything-is-a-class OOP, and lets you write module-level functions when creating your own "author collection" class is too cumbersome for your needs:

```
authors = [Author(name, articles) for name, articles in input_data]
def articles_by_author(author_name):
    global authors
    for auth in authors:
        if author_name == auth.name:
            return auth.articles
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of a Class as nothing more than a bluprint in code. You know how big factories make one object over and over again easilly? They created a bluprint of that object. Added all the needed components to the bluprint like what should it do, how will it respond to certain events.

When you create your Class you create functions in there that will do a task and sometimes return a value or even another object! You do everything in that class and the beauty of it is that you can then create and object of that class and it will carry all the functions and properties and you can access them all from your new object of that type. Each additional object you create is unique and can be seperate from the other objects.

This is the very basics. Im more than happy to help you. And sorry for not going deeper. Im writting this from my cellphone :)